dbt - Using multiple 'models' folders in one dbt project? Is this a possibility?
For those with dbt experience, is it possible to have multiple 'models' folders in a single dbt project (all aliased as different folder names)?
We have a project where there are multiple clients and we want to segregate their data pipelines by creating a separate models folders for each client in the same project.
For example, client 'a' would have their models in a folder called 'models_[client a]' and underneath would be the main/stage/intermediate folders.
Client 'b' would have a models folder called 'models_[client b]'... etc. I don't see much documentation around this type of set up which makes me think this is not a potential way to set up a working dbt project. If we specify each models folder in the dbt_project.yml file (we are on dbt cloud btw) will dbt build the models correctly?

yes thats possible. Its just a folder structure like we have in windows... you can create folders like model_a/main/stage/intermediate and then model_b/main/stage/intermediate and then model_c/main/stage/intermediate.

You can accomplish this using the models-path config in dbt_project.yml:
model-paths:
  - models_client_a
  - models_client_b

